# Thymeleaf security: content can be edited only when authorized AND the user is not the same as the author of the article

Tags: spring-security, thymeleaf, authorize

I need a user to be able to make rating for a review only is the user is authorized AND the user ID is not the same as  the author ID of the review. How can I add 2 security definitions, in which the other one compares the user ID?

Here is my html:

```
<td class="rating-tab">
     <span th:text="${ratingToUse}"></span>
     <form sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()"
           action="#"
           th:action="@{/addrating}"
           method="post" th:object="${newRating}" class="mt-5">
              <input value="0" type="hidden" class="rating" data-glyphicon="0"
                           th:field="*{stars}">

              <input type="hidden" id="reviewID" name="reviewID" th:value="${oneReview.reviewId}">

          <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" style="margin-top: 10px;">Submit my rating</button>
     </form>
</td>
```

and here is my controller for review and rating:

```
  @GetMapping(value = "/review/add/{id}")
    public ModelAndView getReviewView(@PathVariable String id, HttpServletRequest request) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        ImdbMovieData thisMovie = imdbAPIService.getOneMovieOnly(id);
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        User customUser = (User)authentication.getPrincipal();
        int userId = customUser.getId();
        String userName = customUser.getUserName();
        modelAndView.addObject("review", new Review(userName, userId));
        modelAndView.addObject("thisMovie", thisMovie);
        modelAndView.setViewName("add-review");
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

and

```
 @PostMapping(value = "/addrating")
    public ModelAndView addRating(@Valid Rating ratingToAdd, BindingResult bindingResult, HttpServletRequest request) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        Review thisReview = reviewService.findByReviewID(ratingToAdd.getReviewID());
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        User customUser = (User)authentication.getPrincipal();
        int userId = customUser.getId();
        if(userId == thisReview.getUserId()){
            modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:read-review/" + ratingToAdd.getReviewID());
            return modelAndView;
        }

        if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
            ratingService.saveRating(ratingToAdd);
        }
        Review reviewToUpdate = reviewService.findByReviewID(ratingToAdd.getReviewID());
        if (reviewToUpdate.totalRatingCount == null && reviewToUpdate.totalRatingSum == null) {
            reviewToUpdate.totalRatingCount = 1;
            reviewToUpdate.totalRatingSum = ratingToAdd.getStars();
        }
        else {
            reviewToUpdate.totalRatingCount++;
            reviewToUpdate.totalRatingSum += ratingToAdd.getStars();
        }
        reviewService.saveReview(reviewToUpdate);
        modelAndView.setViewName("redirect:read-review/" + ratingToAdd.getReviewID());
        return modelAndView;
    }
```

Comment: One simple way is to use Thymeleaf's [conditional operators](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#simple-conditionals-if-and-unless) to control whether a part of the site (such as a form) is displayed or hidden. You can have multiple conditions using `and`. That may be sufficient for your needs, in this case. But you may want to prevent unauthorized users from even being able to reach the page in the first place. That is probably better handled by page navigation rules, not Thymeleaf tags.